Why does SetOptions[Tree,ImageSize->Tiny] fail for Tree[]
It works for Plot but not for Tree
SetOptions[Tree, ImageSize -> Tiny]
Options[Tree, ImageSize] (*gives {ImageSize -> Tiny}*)
{Tree[{{1, 2}, 3}], Tree[{{1, 2}, 3}, ImageSize -> Tiny]}

SetOptions[Plot, ImageSize -> Tiny];
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2  Pi}];
plot2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2  Pi}, ImageSize -> Tiny];
{plot1, plot2}

$Version is "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

